# How to substitute text which has implicit meaning in vi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vi, substitution

I have a C code in vi from which I want to replace the text "\n" with something else. Use of %s:\n:(anything else) isn't working. Is there any way to bypass this?

For example,a line in the code is: printf("Hello world\n");
In vi, I need to replace "\n" in the printf line with a full stop. Use of substitue command (%s:\n:.) will not work for "\n"

Please let me know what is the command to replace 'text' which also has some implicit meaning in vi (here \n is newline is vi as well).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to post the code you have tried, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: If I understand your question you want to escape the escape character ("\").  Easy.  For example: `:%s/<dog\/>/<cat\\>`.  Or, for just the current line:  `:%s/<dog\/>/<cat\\>`.  Or, in your case, `%s/\\n//g` will delete all occurrences of "\n" in the entire file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in `\n`, like this:

```
%s:\\n:.
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. You may click the accept button if this answers your question.